# How can I make this launch better?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I tried to launch this pawn away with some rigid body physics, but it just slides off and doesn't look very convincing in terms of speed and the overall movement. I like the way the square flips up but it should launch the pawn accordingly. What settings need to be added/improved?[image: it slides off instead of launching]
[the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QuYQJK0TJUAtl2HkBR1WKuZsgxd0tuXU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4):

You could create another object that you'll make invisible and that will be the one that will really push the pawn, make its movement fast so that it's more powerful than your square:

[image]

You could also cheat with some keyframes. Create one locrotscale keyframe for your pawn when it's on the square:

[image]

Create a second locrotscale keyframe where it's supposed to be ejected, plus a keyframe on the *Animated* option off:

[image]

The previous frame, enable the *Animated* option on and keyframe it:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: poor little pawn...you are so cruel!!

Comment: Chris, this is all fake, no pawn has been hurt actually, how don't you know that after all these years

Comment: whaaaat? really.....? and u and moderators...all fake!?!??!

Comment: of course, and you are in a matrix